# json multi array syntax

Tags: php, json

I create array for json this's multiple array condition with syntax :

```
$row_set = array(
    "err" => "",
    "msg" => "",
    "data" => array(
        "f" => "",
        "hotel"=> array(
            "att" => "",
            "name" => "name",
            "city" => "",
            "country" => ""
        ),
        "city" => array(
            "att" => "",
            "name" => "",
            "region" => "",
            "country" => "",
            "nr_hotels" => ""
        )
    )
);

echo json_encode($row_set);
```

But when I test it in jsonlint.com there is an error :

```
Parse error on line 1:
array("err"=>"","ms
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

Please help me. Where is the error from my syntax?

Comment: I copied your code and try jsonlint.com and it said Valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code generates:

```
{"err":"","msg":"","data":{"f":"","hotel":{"att":"","name":"name","city":"\r\n","country":""},"city":{"att":"","name":"","region":"","country":"","nr_hotels":""}}}
```

which is perfectly valid JSON.

You are parsing PHP code, not JSON in validator.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is run perfect on `jsonlint`

```
$row_set =array(
        "err"=>"",
        "msg"=>"",
        "data"=>array(
                "f"=>"",
                "hotel"=>array(
                        "att"=>"",
                        "name"=>"name",
                        "city"=>"",
                        "country"=>""
                        ),
                "city"=>array(
                        "att"=>"",
                        "name"=>"",
                        "region"=>"",
                        "country"=>"",
                        "nr_hotels"=>""
                        )
        ));
echo json_encode($row_set);
```

**Output**

```
{"err":"","msg":"","data":{"f":"","hotel":{"att":"","name":"name","city":"","country":""},"city":{"att":"","name":"","region":"","country":"","nr_hotels":""}}}
```

You have to copy `json_encode` output on `jsonlint` and you tried to copy php array which is wrong.

Check **[Output](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d93j7kp81)**